# Dependency property in custom control bound to dependency property in parent user control is not updated before custom control DataContext is set

Tags: user-controls, dependency-properties

I created a custom textbox to include validation.  In this control is a dependency property called InputType.  I capture the binding expression and add the rules when the datacontext is changed on the textbox.

```
public partial class ValidationTextBox : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InputTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(InputType),
        typeof(TypeOfInput),
        typeof(ValidationTextBox),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(TypeOfInput.Text));

    private void TextBoxDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //...
        SetBinding();
        AddRules();
    }
```

This works correctly when I use this custom control directly in an application.  The dependency property is set then the data context is set. All is good as the rules are created after the property is set.  However, if I add this custom control inside a user control and bind it's property to the user control's property of the same type in order to expose that property to the consumer of the user control, the rules are created before the custom control properties are set.

```
<UserControl ...

    <local:ValidationTextBox 
        InputType="{Binding InputType, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

In this case, the dependency property of the user control is set, then the custom control data context is set, then the custom control dependency property is set.  This means the rules are set using the dependency property default value rather than the actual value.

Is there a way to force the dependency property in the custom control to be updated prior to that control's datacontext being set or the control loaded?

I tried UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged but that doesn't work.

I have a bit of a hack that works.  What I do is reset the rules when the InputType is set on the custom control by using a propertychangedcallback.  This ensures the rules are set after the property is changed.  The issue is that I have several more properties like InputType in the same control and again exposed to the user control and resetting the rules for each property seems like a bad idea.  Any better solutions?